# Why do I keep getting an error when I use a variable in my stripe amount?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to display the amount of my object (Service) in my Stripe.create however, whenever I replace the number with a variable that holds that number I get an error 400 from stripe.

I've tried replacing the number with different types of variables but it seems that only when I put a direct integer it works.

```
    @service_name = @service.name

    @service_price = @service.price <-- {Tried this but doesn't work.}
    @service_price = 9999 <-- {Tried this and it DOES work.}

    require "stripe"

    Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:secret_key]

    token = params[:stripeToken]

    # Create a Customer:
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        email: @email,
        source: token,
      )

    # Charge the Customer instead of the card:
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
        amount: @service.price, <-- {This gives me an error}
        currency: 'usd',
        customer: customer.id,
        description: @service_price <-- {But, this doesn't and it displays correctly}
    })
```

Each service has a price and I would like it to just display the price for that specific associated service.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `@service_price = @service.price` with `@service_price = @service.price.to_i` and it should work. The `to_i` will convert it into an integer before it is further processed!

Comment: I tried this, but it still gives me an error. The same error 400. This makes no sense to me because it should work.